# Wreath product of subgroup with symmetric group

Tags: symmetric-groups, semidirect-product, direct-product, wreath-product, subgroup-growth

I am going through [Generic Quantum Fourier Transforms](http://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0304064.pdf) by Moore et al. I would like to put the screenshot of the section I am confused about below.

[image]

So, Why does $H$ need to be of size $poly(n)$ for the sequence to become true? What happens when $|H| >> $poly(n)$?